# If $\gcd(m,n) =1, $ then $m\mathbb{Z}/ mn\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}/(n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

> If $\gcd(m,n) =1, $ then $m\mathbb{Z}/ mn\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}/(n)$.

Here is my proof to the a/m problem. But I did not make use of $\gcd(m,n) =1.$ Could anyone hence point out and explain the mistakes in my proof? Thank you.

$\text{Define}\ \phi: m\mathbb{Z}/ mn\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/(n)$ by $\phi(ms + mn\mathbb{Z})= [s']_n, \text{where}  \ s \in [s']_n \ \text{and} \ s' \in \{0,...,n-1\}$

$\phi$ is well-defined:

$mx + mn\mathbb{Z} = my + mn\mathbb{Z}$

$\implies mx = my + mr,$ for some $r\in \mathbb{Z}$

$\implies n | x-y$

$\implies [x]_n = [x']_n= \phi(mx + mn\mathbb{Z}) = [y]_n = [y']_n= \phi(my+ mn\mathbb{Z})$

$\phi$ is injective:

It suffices to prove that $\ker(\phi) =\{mn\mathbb{Z}\}.$

Since $\phi(0+mn\mathbb{Z}) = [0]_n, \ker(\phi) \neq \emptyset.$ Given $x = ms+mn\mathbb{Z} \in \ker(\phi),\ $ $ \phi(x)= [s]_n = [0]_n$ $\text{hence}\  s = nk,  \text{for some}\  k \in \mathbb{Z}.$

Clearly, $mnk + mn\mathbb{Z}\subseteq mn\mathbb{Z}.$ Given $y \in mn\mathbb{Z},$ let $y = mnk + (mnc -mnk),$ for some $c \in \mathbb{Z}.$ Then $y \in mnk + mn\mathbb{Z},$ i.e. $mnk + mn\mathbb{Z} = mn\mathbb{Z} $ and hence $\ker(\phi) =\{mn\mathbb{Z}\}.$

$\phi$ is homomorphism:

Let $a = ms + mn\mathbb{Z}, a' = ms'+ mn\mathbb{Z} \in m\mathbb{Z}/mn\mathbb{Z}. $ Then, $\phi(a+a')= \phi(m(s+s') + mn\mathbb{Z}) $  $\exists r \in \{1,...,n-1\}$ such that $[r]_n = [s+s']_n$ and so $\phi(m(s+s') + mn\mathbb{Z}) = \phi(mr + mn\mathbb{Z}) = [r]_n = \phi(a) +_n \phi(a').$

$\phi$ is surjective:

$\text{Given} \ [r]_n \in \mathbb{Z}/(n),\ 
\text{let}  \ x= mr + mn\mathbb{Z}. \ \text{Then}  
\ \phi(x) =[r]_n$

Answer (score 3):

Not making use of $\gcd(m,n)=1$ is not a mistake: The condition is redundant. 
The map $\mathbb Z\to m\mathbb Z$, $x\mapsto mx$ induces an isomorphism $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z\to m\mathbb Z/nm\mathbb Z$.